# Unable to get Paros Proxy to work when connected to a VPN

Tags: security, testing

Using Paros proxy for network sniffing, when we are connected to a VPN network.. Paros doesn't sniff anything. 
On a public network, its able to capture data with the right configuration..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use OWASP ZAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP instead ;)

Paros hasnt been updated for *many* years, while ZAP is an open source fork of Paros and is very actively maintained.

Simon (ZAP Project lead)